# File not found in Java

Tags: java, file

I have following project structure:

```
src
--Main.java
--resources
----Users.txt
```

And I am trying to create a file from Main.java like that:

```
      File file = new File("resources/Users.txt");
```

However, I never succeed at doing so.

Why?

Comment: Any errors? If yes, then what?

Comment: Actually no errors what so ever. The when I debug the file is null

Comment: `new File(...)` can never yield a null pointer. Please include a complete and minimal example.

Comment: If it is a regular file outside a .jar, you are using a relative path. That means, the path to the file is formed from the path where you are calling the file from + the relative path. To make it work, you should invoke java within src folder

Comment: @Nadir, you are the one who helped. Thank you! Please, post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a regular file outside a .jar, you are using a relative path. That means, the path to the file is formed from the path where you are calling the file from + the relative path. To make it work, you should invoke java within src folder